# Real representations of SL(2,C)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there a classification of real-linear (rather than complex-linear) finite-dimensional representations of SL(2,C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the level of the Lie algebra, this is the same as the real representation theory of $SO(3,1)$. Theory of irreducible representations of simple real Lie algebras is well-developed, see for instance [this book](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=18).

Comment: This is not strictly true, one would want to look for real projective representations of $SO(1,3)$. Without this caveat one will miss the Majorana fermion representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, which is irreducible over the reals.

Comment: @Craig: I was talking about the representation theory of real Lie algebras. I thought it was clear. Otherwise one has to take the identity component of the Lorentz group. Since the group is simply connected, projective representations are automatically accounted for.

Comment: The 4-dimensional Majorana spinor rep of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, *is* a real Lie algebra, homomorphic to the aforementioned Lie algebra. Yet it is not strictly speaking a representation of $SO(1,3, \mathbb{R})$, it is only a projective representation. In some sense you have missed "half" of all real representations of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ by promoting oneself to $SO(1,3, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Craig: As I said, on the level of Lie algebra, it does not matter, otherwise indeed one uses the spin group.